# Pandas multiple intersections from list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe containing various sports matches. Columns include `c_away` (away team code), `c_home` (home team), `y` (year) and some others. I'm trying to implement a 'filter' system. For example, find all games where TeamA played at home vs TeamB in 2018.

I can do this manually but as I add more filters it's not really brilliant.

Example:

```
df[(df.c_home == t)|(df.c_away == t)] # any matches involving `t` team
df[(df.c_home == t)&(df.y == 2018)] # matches at home, in 2018
```

My goal was to add to a list:

```
filters.append((df.c_home == t))
if year:
    filters.append((df.y == year))
```

Then `&` them together at the end.

Comment: it will be very helpful if you can add a sample data(as text and paste it here), 5 rows should be enough. Also an expected output please

Comment: Not sure there's really a way around this. One option is to write a small function that allows you to filter on home and/or away and/or year, that way yo can call it simply like `my_filter(df, home='t', year=2018)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the only way, but it seems `df.query` is a bit more useful, since I can just concat strings:

```
filters.append("col == 1")
filters.append("col2 > 3")
df.query(" and ".join(filters))
```